# lebesgue measure in $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I found this in an old exam and I am not sure if what I've done is correct.

Let $E=[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ find a closed set $F$ such that the Lebesgue measure is at least 3/4

Should I suppose that closed here means closed in the subspace topology in $E$ or it is in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$?

here what I've done:

Consider $\lbrace q_n\rbrace_{n\geq 1}$ the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ and take $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{4}$. For each $q_n$ we can consider the open interval $I_n$ whose Lebesgue measure is given by $m(I_n)=\frac{\varepsilon}{2^n}$.  Now, let $\tilde{I_n}=I_n \cap E$, it is clear that $m(\tilde{I_n})\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2^n}$ and consider $U = \bigcup_{n\geq 1}\tilde{I_n}\subseteq E$.Now,   $U$ is open in $E$ with the subspace topology, and since $m(U)\leq \varepsilon$ we are done if we take $F=U^c$.

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument accomplishes more than just making a set $F$ closed in the subspace topology of $E$. It creates a subset $F\subset E$ which is closed in $\mathbb R$ (and so certainly also in the subspace topology).

Namely, a countable union $U\subset [0,1]$ of smaller-and-smaller open intervals around rationals is open in $\mathbb R$, and can be made to have arbitrarily small measure. Its complement in $[0,1]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$, and has measure as close to $1$ as you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

It is not to be understood has "a closed subset in the subset topology" but has "find a closed subset that contains no rational number such that its Lebesgue measure is greater that $\frac{3}{4}$". Otherwise, the answer is trivia : take $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Let $\{q_n\}_{n\geqslant 1}$ be the sequence of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$, and let $\varepsilon >0$ small. Let $I_n = [0,1] \cap (q_n - \frac{\varepsilon}{2n^2},q_n +\frac{\varepsilon}{2n^2})$. Then $U(\varepsilon)=\cup_{n\geqslant 1} I_n$ is open in $[0,1]$ as a union of open subsets. Moreover, its Lebesgue measure is lesser than $\sum_{n\geqslant 1} \frac{\varepsilon}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2\varepsilon}{6}$. Let $F(\varepsilon) = [0,1]\setminus U(\varepsilon)$. It is a close subset of $[0,1]$ that does not contain any rational number, and has Lebesgue measure greater than $1 - \frac{\varepsilon\pi^2}{6}$. Chose $\varepsilon$ small enough so that it has measure greater than $\frac{3}{4}$. For example, $F\left(\frac{2}{3\pi^2 } \right)$ is an answer.